# Can A Derived Class Method be Accessed Indirectly Using Base Class Object Pointer?

Tags: c++, inheritance

When compiling this code, it throws an error that the `getDisjonc()` function is not available in the `Vehicule` class.

```cpp
class Vehicule
{
};

class VehiculeElectrique : public Vehicule
{
    public:
    
    bool getDisjonc()
    {
        std::cout << "The method is working" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Vehicule *vehiculePointer[10];
    
    vehiculePointer[0] = new Vehicule(150,"tunis148484");
    vehiculePointer[1] = new Vehicule(210,"tunis243984");
    vehiculePointer[2] = new VehiculeElectrique(115,"tunis659884");
    vehiculePointer[2]->getDisjonc();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And that's correct, since you have an array of pointers to **`Vehicule`** objects, which does indeed not have a `getDisjonc` member. To solve this you could either look into *polymorphism* or *downcasting*.

Comment: hey , if you have any solution to fix it please let me know

Comment: thanks it works  by downcasting . but how i make my program knows if the object is an instance of base class or child class in a base class array. i want to make the process automated instead of downcasting every member of VehiculePointer array . maybe something like `instanceof` in java.

Comment: Youu seem to really want to use the wrong tool for the job. `dynamic_cast` can be used to  verify if you have an object of derived class or base class, but only for polymorphic classes (i.e. with at least one `virtual` method). But downcasting is almost always not the correct answer from code design perspective.

Comment: it all works fine now,no dynamic_cast needed ,just by creating an array of pointers to Vehicule objects and add at least a virtual method in  class Vehicule  does the job.thanks for your help

Comment: "Getters" and "setters" are usually a sign of bad design. Try thinking of your classes and functions in terms of *behavior* rather than a collection of attributes. Sure you can have attributes, but have them dictate the behavior instead.